# Delegate not firing ios

Tags: ios, delegates

hi i tried to create a delegate to backpass data from tableInterval to ElectricMeter uiViewController
but stil the delegate won't fire.
this is my code
tableInterval h.file

```
@protocol updateIntervalDelegate
@required
-(void)intervalRefresh:(NSString *)interval;
@end


@interface tableInterval : UITableViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, MBProgressHUDDelegate>
{    
IBOutlet UILabel *IntervalLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *EndLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *StartLabel;
MBProgressHUD *HUD;
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *IntervalCell;
__unsafe_unretained id <updateIntervalDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *interval;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *StartDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *EndDate;
@property(nonatomic, assign)id <updateIntervalDelegate> delegate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString* noId;
-(IBAction)PreviousView:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)updateInterval:(id)sender;
@end
```

in m.file

```
@synthesize actionSheet,interval,url,noId,StartDate,EndDate,delegate;
[delegate intervalRefresh:interval.text];
```

calling the delegate method.

so this is in the implementation class .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "tableInterval.h"
#import "ListMeterCell.h"
#import "PopoverView.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h" 



@interface ElectricMeterController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, PopoverViewDelegate,MBProgressHUDDelegate,updateIntervalDelegate> {
PopoverView *pv;
MBProgressHUD *HUD;
}
```

in .m file

```
-(void)intervalRefresh:(NSString *)interval{
NSLog(@"delegate fired!");

NSDictionary *copy=[updatedInfo mutableCopy];
[copy setValue:interval forKey:@"interval"];
[temp removeObjectAtIndex:path.row];
[temp insertObject:copy atIndex:path.row];

[self.MeterList reloadData];

}
```

so the nslog not fired, why? did i miss something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You set controllerName.delegate = self; ???
I think that must be the only problem you should set the delegate first .

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern when calling delegate:

```
if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(intervalRefresh:)])
    [delegate intervalRefresh:interval.text];
else NSLog(@"delegate (%@) not responding", delegate);
```

to ensure delegate property is set and delegate object implements protocol.

Comment: so i put this on the segue function

    `code`else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toTimeInterval"]){
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        tab=[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        tab.noId=self.no;
        tab.delegate=self;
    }`code`

the delegate!
Solved!